# How we can set alarm Manager service

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AlarmManager - How to repeat an alarm at the top of every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127351/alarmmanager-how-to-repeat-an-alarm-at-the-top-of-every-hour)

Can someone please guide me how we can set multiple AlarmManager in android.

I want to run rest api using the AlamManager services.

I have two time to run repeating services.
first aftrer every two mins.
Second end of the(eg 12.00).

How we can set the MutlialarmManager service.

Comment: To set several alarms on different time with different repeat intervals - is that what you want?

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012563/android-how-to-repeat-a-service-with-alarmmanager-every-15-minutes-but-only-ru) question for a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This example is an update for each 10 sec. So u have to adapt it to your work.

```
new Thread(){
@Override
public void run(){
   autoUpdate = new Timer();
   autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  // TODO
              }
           });
      }
    },0,10000);//updates each 10 sec.
 }
 }.start();
```

Hope this will help.