# How to make android aplication run every hour

Tags: android, service, background, autorun

Hello, i'm try to make an auto run application in android,

Example : App to read call log

1. My app runs in background and it runs once in an hour to get all call log from past one hour.

   Can anyone help me to built an application like that?

Thanks for answers

Comment: Answer *is* in your question. Develop *services*.

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`.

code here:  [How to execute one task every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630365/how-to-execute-one-task-every-hour)

and here:   [AlarmManager - How to repeat an alarm at the top of every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127351/alarmmanager-how-to-repeat-an-alarm-at-the-top-of-every-hour)

[AlarmManager - How to repeat an alarm at the top of every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127351/alarmmanager-how-to-repeat-an-alarm-at-the-top-of-every-hour)

Answer (score 0):

Android's [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) can perform the job you want to do.