# Android - get location after some time

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I can get location using LocationManager taking minDistance and minTime.

But how can I get location every 15 secs, for example? (even if an user didn't move)

```
        if (Utils.hasProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15000, 100f, this);
        }

        if (Utils.hasProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 15000, 100f, this);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google docs say that

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime
>   milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location
>   providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime
>   should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

Thus there is an AND condition involved. So you should set your distance parameter to 0. In that case you will get location update every 15 seconds.

Comment: Hm...it's strange. When I set distance parameter to 0 and any minTime (5000, 10000, 20000)- I get location every sec (user is moving at that time)

Comment: How are you verifying that the duration is 1 sec?

Comment: in logs. I see updates every 1 sec but I set 15000 in minTime, for example

Answer (score 0):

Use AlarmManager to do this.See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127351/alarmmanager-how-to-repeat-an-alarm-at-the-top-of-every-hour).Replace the time to 5 minutes.

Or else,you can use

```
         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

         public void run() 
                {
                    //Your code to fetch location
                }
            };

            Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            handler1.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
```

Here 15000 is 15 seconds.

Comment: The alarmManager would make a call with a minimum time of 5 minutes as you said, but the user wants it to be every 15s.

Comment: He can change the time to whatever he wants.See the updated code

Comment: The minimum allowed by Android is 5min. If you put less then that it shows a warning.

Comment: What if it is a Service class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntentService and on onstartcommand call runnable to post you location, like this

```
   Handler handler.postDelayed(postGpsRunnable, 15000);
```